# Sphinx: List of supported languages for highlighting?

Tags: documentation-generation, python-sphinx, pygments

I'm using Sphinx for code documentation and use several languages within the code, I would like to setup highlighting for all of that code. Sphinx briefly mentions a few of the languages it supports ([on this page](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/markup/code.html)), and then mentions that it uses [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) for lexical analysis and highlighting. Sifting through the documentation for both Sphinx and Pygments yielded me no clue on how to do something like highlight objective-c code.

Pygments does mention the list of languages it supports, [here](http://pygments.org/languages/), however that doesn't tell me the exact syntax that I must use within Sphinx (.rst files) to tell the code block to highlight for a specific language. For example, to highlight c++ code you simply use this before your code block:

`.. highlight:: c++`

However after trying these I cannot seem to highlight Objective-C code:

```
.. highlight:: Objective-C
.. highlight:: objective-c
.. highlight:: Obj-C
.. highlight:: obj-c
```

Can anyone supply me with the list of languages (as you would refer to them within documentation)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the list is in the file `pygments/lexers/_mapping.py`, in the (autogenerated) dictionary `LEXERS`. In my copy, I see a line

```
'ObjectiveCLexer': ('pygments.lexers.compiled', 'Objective-C', ('objective-c', 'objectivec', 'obj-c', 'objc'), ('*.m',), ('text/x-objective-c',)),
```

I think this should mean that any of the tags `objective-c`, `objectivec`, `obj-c`, or `objc` should work, as long as your version of Pygments is up-to-date. They work for me.

Answer (score 25):

`pygmentize -L lexers` lists all supported lexers.

- http://pygments.org/languages/
- http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/
- http://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/#getting-help

Comment: Wow, best answer by far. I wasted plenty of time with the first two before I noticed this one.

Answer (score 3):

If you install pygments module. You can use this script to get a list of supported highlighters:

```
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers

lexers = get_all_lexers()
for lexer in lexers:
        print "-\t" + lexer[0] + "\n"
        print "\t-\t" + "\n\t-\t".join(lexer[1]) + "\n"
```

First indent level of output will be general name and second level will be short names of highlighters that you can use.

**Example Output**

- Debian Sourcelist

  - sourceslist
  - sources.list
- Delphi

  - delphi
  - pas
  - pascal
  - objectpascal

[Source](http://haisum.github.io/2014/11/07/jekyll-pygments-supported-highlighters/)